# Expressing a CDF with positive support as a mixture of two components

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, mixing, mixing-variables

Consider the two-component mixture
$$
F(z)=\lambda F_1(z)+(1-\lambda)F_2(z)
$$
where all the $F$'s are CDFs and $\lambda\in [0,1]$.

**A1:** Assume that $F(z)=0$ $\forall z\leq 0$.

---

**Claim:**

A1 implies that $F(\cdot)$ **is not compatible** with

- $F_1(\cdot)$ such that $F_1(z)>0$ for some $z\leq 0$ and $\lambda>0$.
- (In light of the previous bullet point) $F_1(\cdot)$ and $F_2(\cdot)$ both [Logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution). This is because the Logistic CDF is zero only in the limit for any value of the scale and location.

---

**Question: is the claim correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some $z\le 0 $ ,$F(z) = 0$ and $F_{1}(z) > 0$ , then $F_{2}(z) < 0$ , but a CDF can't have this property .

Since the CDF of the logistic distribution has positive values on the negative domain the second claim is also true .

Comment: Thanks. Could you add to your answer a reference to the two bullet points of my claim? In particular, I understand from your answer that my first bullet point is correct. What about the second?

Comment: what do you mean by Logistic ... is ther a formula for this CDF

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution

Comment: if this is for applied purposes, the $F_1$ and $F_2$ would likely be truncated yes

Comment: I edited the answer . The second point is also true .